# Uniformly regular measure "Babiker"

Tags: measure-theory

A regular Borel (Radon) probability measures $\mu$ on compact Hausdorff space $X$ is called uniformly regular if:

> There is a countable family $\mathcal{A}$ of compact $G_\delta$-subsets of $X$ such that for every open set $U\subseteq X$ and every $\epsilon >0$, there is $A\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $A\subseteq U$ and $\mu(U\setminus A)<\epsilon$,

or equivalently,

> There is a sequence $\{U_n\}$ of open subsets of $X$ such that $\mu(K)=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(U_n)$ for every compact set $K\subseteq X$ and $K\subseteq U$.

I have seen in many papers, it is said:

> "Clearly" Every measure $\mu$ on compact metric space is uniformly regular?

So I do not know how to prove this fact? anything idea is appreciated!

Comment: What does "Babiker" mean?

Comment: This notion was first introduced by Babiker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a metric space, closed sets are $G_\delta$ and there is $(U_k,k\in\Bbb N)$ a countable basis of open sets. For each $k$, consider $(K_{k,j},j\in\Bbb N)$ a sequence of compact subsets of $U_k$ such that $\mu(U_k\setminus K_{k,j})<2^{-k}j^{-1}$.

It is possible since in this context an open set is a countable union of closed sets.

Let $U$ open and $\varepsilon>0$. Then $U=\bigcup_{k\in I}U_k$ for some $I\subset\Bbb N$. There is $N$ such that $\mu(U\setminus\bigcup_{k\in I\cap [N]}U_k)<\varepsilon$. Now for $k\in [N]$, take $j$ such that $j^{-1}<\varepsilon$. Then $K:=\bigcup_{k=1}^NK_{k,j}$ gives what we want.